# use react-native-google-signin with custom domain

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I have google signin in a web and a react native app (android and ios).

I can login in both platforms but the token data differs (and because of that the app's one is invalid)

I've looked the docs and try multiple params in different fields but no success

app configuration:

```
      // scopes: ['profile', 'email'], // it doesn't matter if commented or not
      // webClientId: '**********.apps.googleusercontent.com', //
      // offlineAccess: false, // if you want to access Google API on behalf of the user FROM YOUR SERVER
      // hostedDomain: 'https://securetoken.google.com/**********', // if I use this, (or other strings I tried, cant login
      // loginHint: '',
      forceConsentPrompt: true,
      accountName: '**********', // 
      // accountName: '**********:android:**********', // nothing happens
      iosClientId: '**********.apps.googleusercontent.com', // is different from the android one
```

web configuration (with firebase):

```
      apiKey: "**********",
      authDomain: "**********.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://**********.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "**********",
      storageBucket: "",
      2: "**********",
      appId: "**********:web:**********"
```

web token infromation:

```
 {
    "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/**********",
    "aud": "**********",
    "sub": "**********",
    "email": "**********@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "name": "**********",
    "picture": "**********",
    "auth_time": 1568973313,
    "user_id": "**********",
    "sign_in_provider": "google.com",
    "iat": **********,
    "exp": **********,
    "firebase": {
      "identities": {
        "google.com": ["**********"],
        "email": ["**********@gmail.com"]
      }
    }
  }
```

app token information:

```
 {
    "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "azp": "**********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "aud": "**********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub": "**********",
    "email": "**********@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "name": "**********",
    "picture": **********",
    "given_name": "**********",
    "family_name": "**********",
    "locale": "es",
    "iat": **********,
    "exp": **********
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manage to solve it using also firebase (firebase.initializeApp(/*params*/)) , first I do a login with `react-native-google-signin` and then, if success, login with firebase to obtain the correct token:

```
// login with google, on web is unnecesary, to use native interface
const { user } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
const googleTokens = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();

// login with firebase, to get the correct token
const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleTokens.idToken, googleTokens.accessToken);
const auth = firebase.auth();
await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

// get firebase token and user email
const idToken = auth.currentUser && (await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true));
const email = user && user.email;

// login into my back
if (idToken && email) googleLogIn(email, idToken);
```